# Display a json object in a html table

Tags: jquery, json

I want to display a JSON object but rather am displaying the array size. Below is the Json:

```
[{"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2010"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2011"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2012"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2013"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2014"}]
```

How do I display these objects in an html table say the table will have 5 columns, and i want each to have the data for example column o to have yr_end:"FY 2010", next will have "FY 2011" and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = [{"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2010"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2011"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2012"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2013"},
 {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
 {"yr_end":"FY 2014"}];

var y = t[9];

console.log(y['yr_end']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [{"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
         {"yr_end":"FY 2010"},
         {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
         {"yr_end":"FY 2011"},
         {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
         {"yr_end":"FY 2012"},
         {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
         {"yr_end":"FY 2013"},
         {"zse_ticker":"CBZ"},
         {"yr_end":"FY 2014"}];

var text = '';
var length = obj.length;
// print all "yr_end"
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
  if(obj[i]['yr_end'] !== undefined){
    text += obj[i]['yr_end'] + "\n";
  }
}

alert(text);
```